# Using WPF MVVM Light DispatcherHelper

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, data-binding, mvvm-light

I have a WPF Application in which some controls properties are bound to properties in the relative viewmodel.

Here is the relevant XAML code:

```
[..]
<StackPanel>
    <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding ServiceStatus.Colore}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ServiceStatus.Stato}" FontSize="8"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
[..]
```

This is the DTO:

```
public class StatusDTO
{
    public Service.StatoServizio ServiceStatus { get; set; }
    public string Stato { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Colore { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private StatusDTO _ServiceStatus;
    public StatusDTO ServiceStatus 
    {
        get { return _ServiceStatus; }
        set { _ServiceStatus = value; }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {   
        [...]         
        _ServiceStatus = new StatusDTO();

        _ServiceStatus.ServiceStatus = SS_UNKNOWN;
        _ServiceStatus.Stato = "INITIALIZING...";
        _ServiceStatus.Colore = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);

        CheckServiceStatus();
        [...]
    }

    private void CheckServiceStatus()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
           {
               Service.StatoServizio ss = SS_UNKNOWN;
               while (true)
               {
                   Thread.Sleep(5000);
                   ss = Service.ServiceManager.GetServiceStatus();

                   if (_ServiceStatus.ServiceStatus == ss)
                       continue;

                   _ServiceStatus.ServiceStatus = ss;
                   switch (_ServiceStatus.ServiceStatus)
                   {
                       case SS_STOPPED:
                           _ServiceStatus.Stato = "STOPPED";
                           _ServiceStatus.Colore = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                           break;
                      [...]
                   }

                   DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => { RaisePropertyChanged("ServiceStatus"); });  <----- HERE I GOT THE EXCEPTION
               }
           });                  
    }
```

The DispatcherHelper is initialized in App.xaml.cs

When the code executes the lambda in *DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI* I got this exception:

```
Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject
```

If I update the _ServiceStatus in the UI thread (as in the constructor of the viewmodel) the ui gets updated.

My question is: isn't *DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI* there to avoid this issue? What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to call the RaisePropertyChanged method from a background thread without using the DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI method.

Comment: Already tried but the result is the same exception

Comment: The brush is probably your issue. Please refer to my answer.

Comment: As a side note, if you're creating Brushes in the view model, you're probably doing something wrong. View models should rarely be aware of things like Color, Brush, Visibility, etc. If you are interested, feel free to join the [WPF Chat Room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf). We specialize in WPF with MVVM, and are generally arund most work days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should either create the `Colore` brush on the UI thread or call its `Freeze` method on the background thread:

```
case SS_STOPPED:
_ServiceStatus.Stato = "STOPPED";
_ServiceStatus.Colore = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
_ServiceStatus.Colore.Freeze(); // <--
break;
```

Comment: Yes, freezing solves the problem, but doesen't CheckBeginInvokeOnUI meant to avoid the use of freezing by executing the RaisePropertyChanged in the main UI thread?

Comment: No. It simply calls the delegate (RaisePropertyChanged in this case) on the UI thread. It doesn't freeze the brush for cross-thread access. As I mentioned in the first comment, you don't need to call the RaisePropertyChanged  on the UI thread.

Comment: But as far as I understood (I'm new to the whole mvvm & wpf thing), as far as the properties are updated on the main thread there is no need to freeze the property. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, if you create a freezable such as a brush on a background thread you must explicitly freeze it in order to be able to use it on another thread such as the UI thread.